# After updating JComboBox, how to refresh length of box

Tags: java, swing, listener, jcombobox, jtextfield

I am trying to create a way to update a JComboBox so that when the user enters something into the text field, some code will process the entry and update the JComboBox accordingly.The one issue that I am having is I can update the JComboBox, but the first time it is opened, the box has not refresh the length of the options in it and as seen in the code below it displays extra white space. I do not know if there is a better different way to do this, but this is what I came up with.

Thanks for the help,

Dan

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Catch{
public static JComboBox dropDown;
public static String dropDownOptions[] = {
         "Choose",
         "1",
         "2",
         "3"};
 public static  void main(String[] args) {
     dropDown = new JComboBox(dropDownOptions);
     final JTextField Update = new JTextField("Update", 10);
     final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Subnet Calculator");
     final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
     frame.setSize(315,430);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
     Update.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {  
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                dropDown.removeAllItems();
                dropDown.insertItemAt("0", 0);
                dropDown.insertItemAt("1", 1);
                dropDown.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }
              });
        panel.add(Update);
        panel.add(dropDown);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Update.requestFocus();
        Update.selectAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: I launched your code but I don't really understand what the problem is. Actually, I don't understand what the program is supposed to do. As soon as we open the combobox, the values are changed inside and it always display "0", "1".

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. This is just a code snipet of the whole utility. For simplicity here is what I am trying to create. If A is typed in the jtextfield the combobox uses array A. If b is typed in the jtexfield then the combo box contains array B. And so on. I just removed all of that checking portion from the code i uploaded here to try and make the code as simple as possible and leave only my error. The error is the first time the combo box is clicked 0 and 1 are contained but with extra spaces. After that it works fine, just the first iteration isn't functioning properly.

Answer (score 3):

1) `JTextField` listening for `ENTER key` from `ActionListener`

2) remove `FocusListener`

3) example about add new `Item` as last `Item` from `JTextField` to the `JList`, only you have to modify for `JComboBox` and add  method `insertItemAt()` correctly

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ListBottom2 {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    private JList list = new JList(model);
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField("Use Enter to Add");
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    public ListBottom2() {
        model.addElement("First");
        list.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        panel.setBackground(list.getBackground());
        panel.add(list, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JTextField textField = (JTextField) e.getSource();
                DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
                model.addElement(textField.getText());
                int size = model.getSize() - 1;
                list.scrollRectToVisible(list.getCellBounds(size, size));
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ListBottom2 frame = new ListBottom2();
            }
        });
    }
}
```